# double checking GitLab installation : gitlab-shell self-check failed

Tags: git, gitlab

I installed GitLab and everything seems fine. Until I double check application status by running: `sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`. This item is in red and seems to have an error:

```
  gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

I try opening `config.yml` but I don't seem to find any unusual there. You think what am I missing?

Also, I have a custom SSH connection. What I don't understand from this explanation:

```
Custom SSH Connection

If you are running SSH on a non-standard port, you must change the gitlab user's SSH config.

# Add to /home/git/.ssh/config
host localhost          # Give your setup a name (here: override localhost)
    user git            # Your remote git user
    port 2222           # Your port number
    hostname 127.0.0.1; # Your server name or IP
You also need to change the corresponding options (e.g. ssh_user, ssh_host, admin_uri) in the config\gitlab.yml file.
```

Out of lost, I don't have this `/home/git/.ssh/config`, should I create one or I am just missing something?

My call stack:

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.4 ? ... OK (1.7.6)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:29:in `check'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check:11:in `<main>'
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Projects have satellites? ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/local/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.4)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Comment: Are you opening the file with the command listed there? It is possible that the git user cannot open the file, as the file permissions may be incorrect.

Comment: Yes I do. I just did follow what is on the production [readme](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md)

Comment: @LeandroGarcia can you copy the call stack which leads to the error message?

Comment: @VonC - Pardon, but how can I provide you that?

Comment: See https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1615958/1402770/7d0c618c-3ce9-11e3-8546-74536687cdd6.jpg: there is a callstack there.

Comment: You don't need a `~git/.ssh/config`, if your key is at the standard place with a standard name `~git/.ssh/id_rsa`. Simply change the port in the `config/gitlab.yml`.

Comment: I meant *copy*, not paste a picture. You cannot search a picture. A picture means nothing when it comes to error message.

Comment: Do you have a slash in `gitlab-url`? (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3324#issuecomment-16126888)

Comment: @VonC, there pasted it. Pardon for that.

Comment: Yes I do have a trailing slash on gitlab_url.

Comment: Then back to the /etc/hosts (of the gitlab server, as mentioned in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/42#issuecomment-21045139). I have edited my answer.

Comment: @VonC - Man, you nailed it! DNS fix solves the issue. Can you edit your post? So I can checked it as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It could be similar to the [Issue 5437](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5437):

> I ran into the exact same problem doing a clean install on my debian wheezy 7.2 server.
>
> I made two changes and rebooted the server (no problem since it is only a testserver):
>
> - make sure that your domain points to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts` (on my server it pointed to `127.0.1.1`)
> - add `/home/git/.ssh/config` for the non-standard ssh port as mentioned in the installation procedure

In that case, setting the domain to `127.0.0.1` in the `/etc/hosts` was enough.

Other issue possible: [issue 5426](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5426): wrong sidekick command

> This way to start sidekiq does not work anymore. You have to use:

```
sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production script/background_jobs start
```

---

An `http.rb:xxx:in`initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)` error message is seen in:

- [Issue 5151](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5151) => solved by [this comment](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3324#issuecomment-16126888):

  ```
  sudo -u git -H vim /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  # and change:
  gitlab_url: http://yourhost to gitlab_url: http://yourhost/
  # Slash at the end is important.
  ```
- [Issue 42 of gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/42#issuecomment-21045139): again, the `/etc/hosts` is important to get right.

---

The [OP Leandro Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972657/leandro-garcia) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859216/double-checking-gitlab-installation-gitlab-shell-self-check-failed#comment29538710_19859277):

> **I forgot to setup the domain I provided on `gitlab_url`**.
>   Adding that and correcting the DNS on my domain provider solves the issue

Comment: Sadly, both didn't resolved the issue. Doing `sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production script/background_jobs start` doesn't output anything.

Comment: On my `/etc/hosts/` I have this `127.0.0.1 localhost leandro` should either localhost or leandro is the URL that I must specify in the GitLab config?

Comment: I forgot to setup the domain I provided on gitlab_url. Adding that and correcting the DNS on my domain provider solves the issue. Man add this to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @LeandroGarcia Great! I have edited my answer to include your conclusion, for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar for me, I had my Omnibus Gitlab installation all working fine. I was able to run various GIT updates and pushes and pulls.

But then I was changing the host and domain name configurations of the server, and then my gitlab wouldn't responding properly, giving the same sort of errors as above. The actual hostname hadn't changed, but how that hostname was being represented in `/etc/hosts` and on my LAN. I thought that I could do a side-run around problems like this by just setting, in my local `~/.git/config` file, the location of the gitlab server to be it's IP address, but that wasn't enough. I had to ensure that Gitlab's own NGINX config file's representation of it's local hostname was understood by the machine.

In a standard Omnibus Gitlab deployment, your nginx config file is found here: `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/etc/gitlab-http.conf`, 
and you are interested in the `server` part:

`server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name hostname.on.your.domain;`

A quick test is: is that hostname as configured in your gitlab-http.conf file pingable?

`ping hostname.on.your.domain`

if not, then double-triple check your /etc/hosts and networking configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to 7.2.2 and ran into this issue under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have never before looked at Ruby code.

Looking in gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_config.rb around line 54 I find that the definition of redis['bin'] is empty and thus the test in gitlab-shell/bin/check fails.

As a quick hack to get it to work I changed:

`# Build redis command to write update event in gitlab queue
  def redis_command
    if redis.empty?
      # Default to old method of connecting to redis
      # for users that haven't updated their configuration
      %W(env -i redis-cli)
    else
      if redis.has_key?("socket")
        %W(#{redis['bin']} -s #{redis['socket']})
      else
        %W(#{redis['bin']} -h #{redis['host']} -p #{redis['port']})
      end
    end
  end`

to

  `# Build redis command to write update event in gitlab queue
  def redis_command
      # Default to old method of connecting to redis
      # for users that haven't updated their configuration
      %W(env -i redis-cli)
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. 
I had wrong address in my gitlab-shell. 
127.0.0.1:3000 was wrong, because I had to put the same address as I used via web (nginx proxy) for example gitlab.com.